# How to stop redirect "Authorized redirect URIs" on Deny while log in with google authentication

Tags: javascript, asp.net, google-authentication

I am using Google Authentication in Web Application and while log in with Google..if user click on "Deny" option..It still redirect to "Authorized redirect URIs" which i mentioned in [Console Developers of google](https://console.developers.google.com).

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var OAUTHURL = 'https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/auth?';
    var VALIDURL = 'https://www.googleapis.com/oauth2/v1/tokeninfo?access_token=';
    var SCOPE = 'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/userinfo.profile https://www.googleapis.com/auth/userinfo.email';
    var CLIENTID = // My Client Id;


    var REDIRECT = 'http://localhost:49234/Account/GoogleSign';
    var LOGOUT = 'http://accounts.google.com/Logout';
    var TYPE = 'token';
    var _url = OAUTHURL + 'scope=' + SCOPE + '&client_id=' + CLIENTID + '&redirect_uri=' + REDIRECT + '&response_type=' + TYPE;
    var acToken;
    var tokenType;
    var expiresIn;
    var user;
    var loggedIn = false;

    $(document).ready(function () {
        login();
    });
    function login() {
        debugger;      

        var win = window.open(_url, "windowname1", 'width=800, height=600');
        var pollTimer = window.setInterval(function () {
            try {
                console.log(win.document.URL);
                if (win.document.URL.indexOf(REDIRECT) != -1) {
                    window.clearInterval(pollTimer);
                    var url = win.document.URL;                        
                    acToken = gup(url, 'access_token');                        
                    tokenType = gup(url, 'token_type');
                    expiresIn = gup(url, 'expires_in');
                    win.close();
                    validateToken(acToken);
                }
            } catch (e) {
            }
        }, 5000);
    }
    function validateToken(token) {            
        $.ajax({

            url: VALIDURL + token,
            data: null,
            success: function (responseText) {
                //alert("Call")
                getUserInfo();
                loggedIn = true;
                $('#loginText').hide();
                $('#logoutText').show();
            },
            dataType: "jsonp"
        });
    }
    function getUserInfo() {

        $.ajax({
            url: 'https://www.googleapis.com/oauth2/v1/userinfo?access_token=' + acToken,
            data: null,
            success: function (resp) {
                user = resp;
                // console.log(user);
                IsAuthenicated(user.id, user);                   

                $('#txtFirstName').val(user.name);                    
                $('#txtEmail').val(user.email);               
            },
            dataType: "jsonp"
        });
    }        
    function gup(url, name) {
        name = name.replace(/[\[]/, "\\\[").replace(/[\]]/, "\\\]");
        var regexS = "[\\#&]" + name + "=([^&#]*)";
        var regex = new RegExp(regexS);
        var results = regex.exec(url);
        if (results == null)
            return "";
        else
            return results[1];
    }
    function IsAuthenicated(GoogleId, user) { //This function call on text change.

        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "http://localhost:49233/AutoComplete.asmx/IsGoogleAuthenicated", // this for calling the web method function in cs code.
            data: '{GoogleId: "' + GoogleId + '" }',// user name or email value
            contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
            dataType: "json",
            success: OnSuccess,
            failure: function (response) {

            }
        });
    }

    // function OnSuccess
    function OnSuccess(response) {
        //alert('s ' + response.d);
        debugger;
        var retval = response.d;
        if (retval == '0') {            
            $('#txtFirstName').val(user.name);
            $('#txtEmail').val(user.email);
            $('#hdgmailId').val(user.id);
            $('#hgverified').val(user.verified_email);
            $('#hglocale').val(user.locale);
            $('#hdgiven_name').val(user.given_name);

        }
        else {
            window.open("http://localhost:49233/Dashboard.aspx?Id=1&number=" + response.d, "_self");

        }
    }        
</script>
```

Can someone suggest better approach how to handle Deny option? And also if i have opened 2 gmail account in same browser then also it is not redirecting me to my application after click on "Allow" access.